# why shuckel when davening?

Tags: tefilla, derech-eretz-manners

When we are davening we are speaking to Hashem, Malchei Hamlachim. How is it appropriate to shuckel and/or swing ones hands? One is executed for motioning in front of the King.

Comment: "One is executed for motioning in front of the King." What does this mean?

Comment: it's a gemara in chagiga. it is disrespectful to motion before the king